# Get Multi line field value using jquery

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have used the below code to get the single line text field value in the customized NewForm.aspx and its working fine.

```
function PreSaveAction()
  {
  var value = $("input[title="Title"]").val();
  alert(value);
  };
```

If i used the same code to get the value of the multi line text field means it returns undefined. I hope it is because the multi line text content will be in html.

```
function PreSaveAction()
  {
  var value = $("input[title="Notes"]").val();
  alert(value);
  };
```

Please help me to get this html content.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
    var value = $("input[id$='TextField_spSave']").val();
    alert(value);
};
```

The WYSIWYG control in SharePoint 2010 is not an `input` control (well, not exactly). It is a mixture of `div`, `p`, and `span` controls. However, there is a hidden `input` named TextField_spSave that you can use.

For more information, see [jquery can't find richtextbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ae414aec-1dd0-474b-bda7-04092f1c4908/).